# ignore leading ansi escape sequence (^[[K) from isfname

Tags: cword

I am using AnsiEsc to look at colorized terminal printout, the printout contains bold face filenames (e.g. from gcc). This typically looks like

```
^[[01m^[[Kmyfile.cpp:32:21:^[[m^[[K
```

AnsiEsc handles that nicely in the version from [here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#ANSIESC) (the version from [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) has trouble with colorless bold face and with `^[[K`). However, when I want to navigate to a file with `gF`, instead of opening `myfile.cpp`, vim attempts to open `Kmyfile.cpp`. It appears to me that `isfname` captures the `K` that belongs to the escape sequence `^[[K` as part of the filename. Is there a way to exclude escape sequences (it seems like only `^[[K` is relevant to me at the moment) from `isfname`?

(I am aware that makeprg and errorformat exist. Please assume I can't use these for whatever reasons—say, the build runs on some CI server and I just get the terminal printout via email)

Comment: You can actually still use the quickfix list. See `:help -q`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I guess I'll do that for now. I'd still like to keep the question for `isfname` as is out of pure interest. (or in case I'll ever come across something that I won't easily fit into `errorformat` …)